# Update Subdocument in Mongodb that stores id(s)

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am developing an application and we have decided to implement database with Mongodb, so I'm truly new to it. In database there is a collection for each company and we need to stores the ID(s) of each category of products of the company in a subdocument of company collection, Let's say we need to insert the following Object into collection:

```
{ 
  name : "comapnyX"
  address : {
     "street" : "main street",
     "ZipCode" : "12345" 
  },
  categories : [
     { "name" : "category1" },  
     { name" : "category2" } 
  ] 
}
```

An then if later on we decide to update the categories, we need add one more category to this subdocument, how do I have to create that update?

please also let me know if this is not a good practice from Datamodeling point of view in Mongodb

Comment: The documentation explains all of this quite well, including the question about modeling. What doesn't make sense? The final specific "how" will depend on what driver you use to access MongoDB from your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **update** method with the **$push** operator to add a new category:

```
db.collection.update( <query>,
                      { $push: { categories: {name: "category3" } }
                   )
```

MongoDB Docs on $push: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/